# Erro ao atribuir Caption com Inc

Tags: delphi

Tenho um componente LISTVIEW, nele são inseridos vários registros. Preciso gerar código Auto Incremento no Caption desse listview de acordo com o número de registros inseridos. Tentei algo do tipo:

```
l := l + 1;
Item.Caption := Inc(l,1);
```

Ele não aceita, da erro. Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Para deixar o conteúdo mais útil para futuros visitantes, poderia [edit] a pergunta para incluir a mensagem de erro que aparecia? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Já resolvi, pra quem tem interesse ou tem o mesmo problema, faça o seguinte:

```
    l := l + 1;
   Item.Caption := inttostr(l);
```